# How to make video stop recording automatically after 5 seconds in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller, ios12

Hi i am using `var imagePicker:UIImagePickerController!` instance to capture the video for 5 seconds but it stopped after one second.

How to fix that?

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
func startCameraFromViewController(type:PickerMode, viewController: UIViewController, withDelegate delegate: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate & UINavigationControllerDelegate) -> Bool {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) == false {
        return false
    }

    pickerMode = type
    self.imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as NSString as String]
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.videoMaximumDuration = 5
}
```

Comment: try with double `imagePicker.videoMaximumDuration = 5.0`

Comment: Ok. i will try @Anbu.karthik. But can you tell me the purpose of using double 5.0

Comment: Your code in question has no issues. Seems like there is some missing code related to the problem not shared in the question.